# Two blocks of content side by side

Tags: html, css

I want to write some content on a website and put a form right next to it like in the example below.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEU6G.png)

This is the code I'm using:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="block1">
<h3>Your body is a temple.</h3>

Schedule an appointment now and start living a better life.
You deserve it.
</div>

<div id="block2">
<em>*Please include correct contact information so we can get back to you.</em>
[contact-form-7 id="28921" title="Make an appointment"]
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width:1000px;
}
#block1 {
    float: left;
    width:500px;
}
#block2 {
    float: left;
    width:500px;
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't display right:

[PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UADgL.png)

I've tried several other ways found here on stackoverflow but I just can't seem to get it working. This is the live site in case it helps: orlandochiropractic.org. You have to go to the strip that says "NEED HELP?" and click on the "MAKE AN APPOINTMENT" button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your problem is on the wordpress form class, look at this element:

`<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f28921-p28210-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">`

Look at this style, it have a `margin-left` set, just overide it with this:

```
div.wpcf7{
   margin-left: 0; //If necessary use !important
}
```

Then i moddified a bit your code to fit the element view, here's follow the code:

```
#wrapper:after{
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}

#block1{
   float: left;
   width: 480px; //Removed 20px beacause you have a padding on the father's div
}

#block2{
   float: left;
   width: 480px; //Same as block1
}
```

Hope it helps your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <h3>Your body is a temple.</h3>
    <p>Schedule an appointment now and start living a better life.
  You deserve it.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <em>*Please include correct contact information so we can get back to you.</em>
    <div>[contact-form-7 id="28921" title="Make an appointment"]</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code dump, doesn't help anyone, apparently the op doesn't know anything about flex box since he's using floats, so it's better if you'd explain what you've done, this is a helping/teaching forum, not a coding service.

Comment: You are not in the position to assume that this person does not know anything about flex box. The op might have heard from it but never used it and can now analyse the code further more to understand it. Any additional questions can always be asked here in the comments. I'll be happy to answer them. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
        #wrapper {
           padding: 20px;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .paoc-popup-modal-cnt{
           padding: 0;
        }
         #block1 {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
        }
        #block2 {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
       }
       div.wpcf7 {
        margin-left: 0;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this css

```
div.wpcf7 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
}
#block1,#block2 {
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
}
.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}
```

and add

div `<div class="clearfix"></div>` below `block2`